# treat '-' as part of a word if it is followed by a letter, but not '>'

Tags: keyword

Is there a way to treat `dashed-as-one-word` but have `this->` split into `this` and `->` instead of `this-` and `>`?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. Neither `bkad/CamelCaseMotion`  nor `chaoren/vim-wordmotion` (the most popular plugins to modify motions) can do this. I would suggest to use `f`, `F`, `t`, `T`, `;`, `,` instead.

Comment: Getting both is hard, but if `iskeyword` does _not_ contain `-` and `>`, `this->val` is 3 words (well, 2, separated by the non-word `->`, but `w` works 3 times).